# Twilio SMS message keeps resending the same message

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

So I'm trying to send notifications to users phones with Twilio, however, the same message is sent three times. I do have three phone numbers hardcoded into an array (providerNumbers) so I think it's looping through three times because of this.

What I'm trying to do is eventually populate the phone numbers array from user-provided phone numbers they store on Firebase for each user. So a different user will receive the same notification to let them know to visit the website.

Here's my `Node.js` code:

```
var providerNumbers = ['number1', 'number2', 'number3'];
var body = "..."

app.get('/testtwilio', function(req, res){
  Promise.all(
    providerNumbers.map(number => {
      return twilio.messages.create({
        to: number,
        from: '+15704058347',
        body: body
      });
    })
  ).then(messages => {
    console.log('Messages Sent!');
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Anyone know how I can prevent the message sending three times to all the users?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

`.map` calls the callback function ***once*** for each element in your `providerNumbers` array.

The callback function sends only ***one*** message when executed.

You can verify this if you log the index with something like this:

```
app.get('/testtwilio', function(req, res){
  Promise.all(
    providerNumbers.map((number, index) => {
      console.log(index);
      return twilio.messages.create({
        to: number,
        from: '+15704058347',
        body: body
      });
    })
  ).then(messages => {
    console.log('Messages Sent!');
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

---

In conclusion, something must be hitting your endpoint `'/testtwilio'` three times.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it's hitting the endpoint three times. I simply run it in Terminal with npm start, sends, then a few seconds later it sends again.

Comment: Try to run directly with node `node your_app_name.js` and call the endpoint from your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to work, try checking the logs to see if multiple requests are being made to the same endpoint. A more concise method of mapping an array of primitives to promises would be using `Promise.map`. Reducing the usage of complex unit structures reduces the number of procedures your code has to perform, makes it easier to debug and to rule out false positives.

```
const providerNumbers = ['number1', 'number2', 'number3']
const from = '+15704058347'
const body = "..."

app.get('/testtwilio', (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.map(
    providerNumbers, 
    to => twilio.messages.create({to, from, body})
  ).then(res => {
    console.log('Messages sent')
    res.json({success: true})
  }).catch(next)
})
```

Comment: `Promise.map()` isn't part of standard javascript. Are you assuming the use of something like Bluebird?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing `app.get` to `app.post`.